# Cmake Compiler unkown

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake build an empty project of mine over the command line.
My project has this barebones file structure

```
-Project
 -Build
 -CMakeLists.txt (empty file)
 -main.cpp (contains hello world and nothing else)
```

I'm running the command "cmake .." in the build folder of the project
However I'm getting this error...

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I have all the required visual studio modules installed, also when I try to configure the same cmake project through the GUI I don't have the same problem and can open the project through visual studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmake%5D+No+project%28%29+command+is+present. In any case, your question is off-topic without a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've updated the question with the necessary info to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue, installing cmake before installing VS is the main cause of this problem. Uninstalling cmake, reinstalling and then restarting your pc seems to fix the issue.